# Node MCU V3 Serial Connection Issues

Tags: serial-port, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am trying to connect my Node MCU V3 with the Arduino IDE on Ventura 13.5.2.
I am using the Board Manager URL "http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json" and the NodeMCU 0.9 (ESP-12 Module).

I am able to Compile my Project, but when I am trying to upload it the error is shown:

"
Variables and constants in RAM (global, static), used 28180 / 80192 bytes (35%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ DATA     1504     initialized variables
╠══ RODATA   972      constants
╚══ BSS      25704    zeroed variables
. Instruction RAM (IRAM_ATTR, ICACHE_RAM_ATTR), used 59747 / 65536 bytes (91%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╠══ ICACHE   32768    reserved space for flash instruction cache
╚══ IRAM     26979    code in IRAM
. Code in flash (default, ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR), used 238768 / 1048576 bytes (22%)
║   SEGMENT  BYTES    DESCRIPTION
╚══ IROM     238768   code in flash
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port /dev/cu.BLTH

A fatal esptool.py error occurred: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/cu.BLTH: [Errno 16] Resource busy: '/dev/cu.BLTH'
"

I understand that the error message tells me that the Serial Port is busy, bt I can't resolve it.

Any tipps on how to overcome this, im new on trying it on Mac OS.

Comment: it is the wrong COM port. select the right one in the Tools menu

Comment: @Juraj I only have one option for the COM Port: /dev/cu.BLTH & /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, so I think it is the right Port I chose. Or is there any way that I disabled the right COM Port?